# MVC3 / C# - Invalid Cast Exception - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net

Anyone know how to remedy this error?

*Specified cast is not valid.*

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

*Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.*

Here is the line of code where it breaks -

```
var id = (int)httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]` is probably a string, therefore you need to parse it:

```
var idStr=(string)(httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
int id;
if(int.TryParse(idStr, out id))
{
    //w00t
}
```

Comment: Thanks...lol...just one thing - Should I put anything in the section that says //w00t

Comment: Yes, that's where you've successfully got a value for `id`. Anywhere else, and you cannot be sure that it parsed to an int correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your value, `httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]` probably doesn't have an int equivalent.

if it's a string, as spender said, you would try,

```
var id = int.Parse("httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
```

intellisence might tell you what type:

`httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]`

is as you type it.  You can also find out in the "watch" tab of your debugger

Answer (score 0):

first call `ToString()`

then `parse` it `to int`

```
int.Parse(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString())
```